# Error when using adrotator to display ads

Tags: xml

I had AdRotator control to display some Banners in my site but I got an error (AdvertisementFile not found). I checked my code and found that everything was as it should be. Please any one help me.

images/Ad_1.jpg
    http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/Category.aspx?cid=25
    
    
    80

images/Ad_2.jpg
    http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/Category.aspx?cid=27
    
    
    80

images/Ad_3.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ac/index.aspx
    
    
    80

images/Ad_4.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ha/ListView.aspx?Category_Id=67
    
    
    80

images/Ad_5.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ha/ListView.aspx?Category_Id=67
    
    
    80

images/Ad_6.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ha/ListView.aspx?ProductCategory_Id=24
    
    
    80

images/Ad_7.jpg
    
    
    
    80

images/Ad_8.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/avs/Display.aspx?catID=38 &amp catName=X-Slim &amp selSub=38
    
    
    80

images/Ad_9.jpg
    http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/Category.aspx?cid=19
    
    
    80

images/Ad_10.jpg
    http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ac/ACProductList.aspx?Id=3
    
    
    80

images/Ad_11.jpg
    http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/Category.aspx?cid=22
    
    
    80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  to create your XML file in such a way that

```
<Advertisements>
 <Ad>
<ImageUrl>~/Images/image1.jpg</ImageUrl>
<height>60</height>
<width>190</width>
<NavigateUrl>http://www.microsoft.com</NavigateUrl>
  <AlternateText>Microsoft Main Site</AlternateText>
  <Impressions>80</Impressions>
  <Keyword>Topic1</Keyword>
  </Ad>
  <Ad>
  <ImageUrl>~/Images/image2.jpg</ImageUrl>
<height>90</height>
<width>90</width>
    <NavigateUrl>http://www.wingtiptoys.com</NavigateUrl>
  <AlternateText>Wingtip Toys</AlternateText>
  <Impressions>80</Impressions>
  <Keyword>Topic2</Keyword>
</Ad>
 </Advertisements>
```

Comment: And also one thing add an Images folder to your application and place the images that you are using in that folder